# NodeJS using request inside a loop

Tags: node.js

I use NodeJS and request lib to make some request to an API.

I understand now that all requests are async and so it doesn't "wait" the result of the GET call, so the index of my Loop is always the same.

I was wondering if there was any simple way (without any lib) to wait for the response of the request call ?

For now, my code is this :

```
for (var i in entries) {    
    var entryId = entries[i]['id'];

    var options = {
        url: 'https://api.com/'+ entryId +'/get/status',
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {
            'Authorization': auth
        }
    };

    console.log(' ENTRY ID > '+ entryId);

    request(options, function(error, response, body) {          
        var response = JSON.parse(body);

        if (response.status.code == 200) {

            var id = response.status.id;
            var data = [];
            data['id'] = id;

            data = JSON.stringify(data);

            // show first entryId of loop  
            console.log(' > MY ID : '+ id + ' - '+ entryId);

            options = {
                host: hostname,
                port: 80,
                path: '/path/function2',
                method: 'PUT'
            };

            var post = http.request(options, function(json) { 
                var body = '';

                json.on('data', function(d) {
                    body += d;
                });
                json.on('end', function() {
                    console.log('> DONE');
                });

            }).on('error', function(e) {
                console.log(e);
            });

            post.write(data);
            post.end(); 
        }
    }); 
}
```

Comment: doesn't the ```async=false``` option work ?

Answer (score 3):

You are looking for async/await.

Wrap your logic inside an async function, then you can await for the promise to resolve.

```
const request = require('request-promise')
async function foo (a) {
   for (i in a)
      try {
         let response = await request('localhost:8080/')
         // response contains your response data.
      } catch (e) {
         console.error(e)
      }  
}
foo([/*data*/])
```

Just use the promisified version of request module.

Answer (score 0):

You also can use Promises to wait for your async code to finish.

```
function asyncCode(msg, cb){
  setTimeout(function() {cb(msg);}, 1000);
}

var p1 = new Promises(function(resolve){
    asyncCode("my asyncCode is running", resolve);
});

p1.then(function(msg) {
    console.log(msg);
}).then(function() {
    console.log("Hey I'm next");
});

console.log("SyncCode, Async code are waiting until I'm finished");
```